# Concurrent ToLookup() conversion?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, concurrentdictionary

How do I make `ToLookup()` concurrent?  I have a some code like this:

```
myRepository.GetAllContacts().ToLookup( c => c.COMPANY_ID);
```

I would like to have a structure similar to this:

```
new ConcurrentDicitonary<String,IEnumerable<Contact>>();  // <Company,List of Contacts in company>
```

Because each `COMPANY_ID` could map to multiple `Contact`, I can't simply use `ToDictionary`.

Comment: Why concurrent? Are you hoping for a speed improvement?

Comment: Yes, I would like to concurrently do some work on all Companies at the same time.

Comment: The only way that concurrency is going to give you any speed improvement is if the time taken to compute `c.COMPANY_ID` is lengthy. Since it is a property is probably lightning fast so the current code will perform far better than using any form of multi-threading. It just takes time to launch threads and to do all of the marshalling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a simple question, but as the other (problematic) answers show, the solution is not really trivial.

**Problems with existing answers**

As it stands, both proposed solutions result in the creation of some kind of dictionary where each time you enumerate the `IEnumerable<Contact>` at any given key, the filtered `IEnumerable<Contact>` is recreated from scratch by enumerating and filtering the original collection. Essentially, what you're storing in the dictionary is the *logic* to get the desired filtered `Contact` collections, not the *actual* collections.

As a result you'll be enumerating the original `IEnumerable<Contact>` over and over. This is dangerous from a thread-safety standpoint and even if it works - there is no benefit to doing this, only overheads.

**Proposed solution**

You are right in that the best out-of-the-box thread-safe alternative for `Lookup/ILookup<TKey, TValue>` appears to be `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` where `TValue` derives from `IEnumerable<Contact>`. It offers a superset of lookup functionality *and* is thread-safe *if you build it correctly*. There is no ready-to-use extension method for this in the Base Class Library, so you can just roll your own implementation:

```
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = GetAllContacts();
ConcurrentDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<Contact>> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IReadOnlyList<Contact>>();

foreach (IGrouping<string, Contact> group in contacts.GroupBy(c => c.COMPANY_ID))
{
    if (!dict.TryAdd(group.Key, group.ToArray())) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Key already added.");
    }
}
```

This looks very similar to what others have offered, but with one important difference: my dictionary's `TValue` is a *materialised* collection (specifically `Contact[]` posing as `IReadOnlyList<Contact>`). It does not get rebuilt from scratch every time you pull it out of the dictionary and enumerate it.

Oh, and also I only enumerate the source `IEnumerable<Contact>` once, ever - not really life-changing, but a nice touch.

You could still use `ConcurrentDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Contact>>` as your dictionary type (you could substitute the dictionary type in my example above and it will still compile and work as expected) - just be sure that you only add *materialised* and, preferably, immutable collections to the dictionary as you're building it.

**Choosing your `TValue` type: alternatives to `IReadOnlyList<T>`**

*(beyond the scope of the original question)*

`IReadOnlyList<T>` is the most generic general-purpose quasi-immutable collection interface I could think of (apart from `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` obviously) that conveys to the callers that the collection is materialised and unlikely to change in the future.

If I were using this in my own code I would actually use `Contact[]` as my dictionary's `TValue` for any private and internal calls (forgoing the comfort of "read-only" for perf reasons). For any public APIs I would stick with `IReadOnlyList<T>` or possibly `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to emphasise the read-only aspect of the `TValue` collection.

If taking an external dependency is a viable option, you could also add Microsoft's `System.Collections.Immutable` NuGet to your project and use an `ImmutableDictionary<string, ImmutableArray<Contact>>` to store your lookup.  `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an immutable thread-safe dictionary. `ImmutableArray<T>` is a lightweight array wrapper which has strong immutability guarantees and also has solid performance characteristics achieved through a struct enumerator and re-implementations of certain LINQ methods which avoid enumerator allocations altogether.

`List<T>` would be a poor choice for `TValue` due to it's a) mutability and b) its tendency to allocate internal buffer arrays whose length is greater than `List<T>.Count` (unless you explicitly use `List<T>.TrimExcess`). When you stash stuff in a dictionary, there's a good chance it'll stay alive for a while, so allocating memory you're not really going to use (like `List<T>` does) is not a great idea.

*EDIT*

Now after all this I have to add: .NET's current `Lookup<Tkey, TValue>` implementation returned by LINQ's `ToLookup` *actually appears to be thread-safe*. However, none of the specs that I found make any guarantees about the thread-safety of instance methods on `Lookup<TKey, TValue>` (MSDN specifically states that they are not guaranteed to be thread-safe), which means that lookup thread-safety is an implementation detail, not a bulletproof guarantee. therefore all I said above re using `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` still applies.

Comment: VERY interesting reply.  I am gonna have to try this next Monday at work.

Comment: +1 but you need to measure if this is faster. I'd say 95% chance of it being significantly slower. The internal coordination in the CD probably kills the parallelization gains.

Comment: Also, the GroupBy must be parallelized as well in order to have even a chance of speeding this up. Otherwise you build a parallel dict *after building a sequential dict*.

Comment: @usr, there is some ambiguity in the question leading us to focus on two different concepts: you're thinking about *building* the lookup in parallel, whereas my focus was on creating a thread-safe lookup which would subsequently be *used* by parallel consumers. Of course creating a `ConcurrentDictionary` will take longer - addressing that was never part of my goal due to the way I read the question.

Comment: I didn't really think of this ambiguity until I saw @Enigmativity's comment (which makes total sense and I, too, don't see much benefit in parallellising the lookup creation).

Comment: What ToLookup returns is already thread-safe for reading. To me it seems this is about creating the lookup.

Comment: I didn't know that the result of ToLookUp was already thread-safe.  In anycase, I tried it, it works, but it's actually slower than single-threaded.  So I had to shelf the changes.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu, so was usr right that you were trying to *build* the lookup in parallel as opposed to using it in parallel once it's ready?

Comment: No, I was actually just trying to USE it in parallel.  The building part didn't take that long so I didn't bother with it.  It was the using part that was taking the majority of run time.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu, at least I got my assumptions right then. `ConcurrentDictionary` is pretty quick, so I'm very surprised re your perf results - they suggest that you're using the lookup it in a way I didn't anticipate. I'd be curious to see the parallel consumer code (if you are allowed to post it and think there's benefit to doing so, of course).

Comment: There isn't any point in posting the code, but to put it simply, I was just  mapping each Company to a export view object stored in a list, then converting the list to CSV, then export out.  Clearly, this can be done in parallel as they don't depend on each other, but I guess each one simply isn't taking long enough to justify the cost of parallelism.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu, your perf could be limited by IO of the export stage (in which case you'll get no benefit in parallelisation), but if the CPU work component is non-negligible, you could benefit from a `Parallel.ForEach` with a limited `DegreeOfParallelism` over your `ILookup`. This does not require concurrent access to the lookup though, so my above answer kinda goes out the window. Matter of fact in this situation I wouldn't even use a lookup - `Parallel.ForEach(contacts.GroupBy(c => c.COMPANY_ID), ...)` will get the job done - if there's benefit to parallelisation it at all of course.